# Should I deploy my web server with Django's default database?

Tags: python, django, database, amazon-web-services, sqlite

I'm a noobie to Django and I'm almost at the stage of deploying a web server.

I was just having some doubts with Django's database. Currently I'm using the default sqlite3 database to store all the user models as well as the info models. I'm thinking of using AWS to deploy my web sever.

So when I get to that stage, should I continue with sqlite or should I switch to AWS's database or something like Firebase. If I continue with sqlite, where and how exactly will the information be stored? And what if I switch to something like PostgreSQL, where will the information be stored and will it be secure/fast (even if I manage to get thousands of users)?

Thanks so much, this question might be really basic but I'm super confused.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`sqlite` is a flat file database, it uses an exposed file in your project to save your data, this is fine in local environment, but when deploying you need to consider that the server and the database are in the same machine and using the same disk. that means if you accidentally remove the machine -and its disk space- used to serve the application, then the database itself will be deleted with all records.

Plus you will face problems if you tried to scale your servers, that is every server will have his own copy of the database and syncing all those files will be huge headache.

If your data is not that important then you can keep using `sqlite`, but if you are expecting high traffic and complex db structure, then I would recommend you consider a db engine like Mysql or maybe look up the databases offered by amazon here:
https://aws.amazon.com/products/databases/

For django, you will need to change the adapter when using a different db like mysql, sqlite or anything else.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/databases/